# Script - Absolute, Relative Paths

Tags: scripting

I'm trying to execute a mono application, without requiring the user to type in 'mono filename'.  It's just one line of code:

```
mono ./Bin/jobshop.exe $1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6 $7 $8 $9
```

It works great, so long as I call it from the correct directory.  But if my current directory isn't exactly where the script is - it fails because the ./Bin is relative to the current directory.  I want it to be relative to the location of the script.

I found that I was able to get the location of the script using

```
echo dirname "$(readlink -f "$0")"/Bin/jobshop.exe $1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6 $7 $8 $9
```

That displays correctly on the screen; but I can't figure out how to put it into my first script such that mono executes that value.

I'm using 'tcsh', however I would prefer an answer agnostic to any shell.

I just want to run
'mono' + 'dirname "$(readlink -f "$0")"/Bin/jobshop.exe $1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6 $7 $8 $9'

But I can't seem to get it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

path=$(dirname $(readlink -e -- "$0"))

/path/to/mono "$path"/Bin/jobshop.exe "$@"
```

- You should save your program path in $path variable.
- Use `"$@"` instead of listing all command line arguments.

Answer (score 2):

You could say:

```
mono $(dirname "$(readlink -f "$0")")/Bin/jobshop.exe $1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6 $7 $8 $9
```