# How to get the filename of a symlink destination in a shell script?

Tags: shell-script, symlink, basename

let's say the scriptname is `myscript`. It's a symbolic link to `thescript_1.91.sh`

Is there a way to get the name of the link destination? 
An example:
I want to write in a logfile

```
cat <<EOF

#########################
`basename $0`
`date -R` 
#########################

EOF
```

$0 holds the name of the file argument to the subshell, that is "myscript"

Is there a way to get the name of the link-destination here?

Comment: Possibly related [Will $0 always include the path to the script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119929/will-0-always-include-the-path-to-the-script) - note in particular the use of `readlink`

Comment: Also related is https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118611/ .

Answer (score 3):

If your system has a `readlink` utility, this would do that.

```
cat <<END_MESSAGE
#########################
$( basename "$( readlink -f "$0" )" )
$( date -R ) 
#########################
END_MESSAGE
```

The `-f` option is used to resolve all symlinks in the given pathname recursively, not just the first link.  See the manual for `readlink` on your system (`man 1 readlink`).

Also related:

- [Have backticks (i.e. `cmd`) in *sh shells been deprecated?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126927)

Comment: See also: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/029

Comment: Hi,

readlink did it! I didn't know that command.

Sometimes I also use the $() convention. But most of the time I use backticks like I did in the last ~25 years....

Thank you!